# A book like "practice and progress"

Tags: book

Many years ago I was learning English and I used an old book "practice and progress". It was great because you read a short text and then reconstruct it with you own words by answering some questions. Is there a similar book for German language learners?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are basically reading comprehension exercises.
If you google the german word (*Leseverstehen*), you find both books and online resources. I reckon it's a good idea to use reading comprehension resources for German primary school (e.g. https://www.stark-verlag.de/zusatzmaterial) but there are resources for adult learners too (e.g. https://mein-deutschbuch.de/leseverstehen.html or https://www.schularena.com/deutsch/leseverstehen/leseverstehen-klassisch-1 or https://www.thalia.de/shop/home/artikeldetails/A1070006831).